# Way to extract Count from description

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I constantly am tasked with pulling information from another source and receive the information without Size denomination. The size or count is in the description and want to be able to write an excel formula with the following logic:

if cell contains Capsules, Tablets, Liquid, etc, then make this cell equal too Capsules, Tablets, Liquid, etc + the number that comes before it

A few example items:

```
Nature's Bounty Magnesium 500 mg, 200 Tablets    
Aerobic Life Mag 07 Oxygen Digestive System Cleanser Capsules, 180 Count    
Natural Vitality Natural Calm Anti Stress Drink 30 count Raspberry Lemon
```

Want the following column to have Tablets or Count if it is said in the description.

I've tried using if and then statements but don't know how to combine them to create 'or' and 'and'

Expect to have the columns from the examples above to look as follows:

```
200 Tablets
180 Count
30 Count
```

Comment: You *could* do this with formulas only, but the formula would be very inefficient, so I'd recommend using VBA instead.  What have you tried so far?

Comment: I also am working on doing this using R, Can't seem to be able to get the and/or statements to work in their as well.

Answer (score 1):

If the values are in column A, the formula would be like that:

```
=+IF(ISERROR(VALUE(RIGHT(LEFT(A3,SEARCH(IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("Tablets",A3)),IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("Capsules",A3)),IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("Count",A3)),"","Count"),"Capsules"),"Tablets"),$A3)-1),4))),0,VALUE(RIGHT(LEFT(A3,SEARCH(IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("Tablets",A3)),IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("Capsules",A3)),IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("Count",A3)),"","Count"),"Capsules"),"Tablets"),$A3)-1),4)))&" "&IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("Tablets",A3)),IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("Capsules",A3)),IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("Count",A3)),"","Count"),"Capsules"),"Tablets")
```

As the formula is long see below separated in two different cells, the first one search which is the item we are looking (Tablets, Capsules or Count) and returns it, the second one search the previous number:

```
+IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("Tablets",A4)),IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("Capsules",A4)),IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("Count",A4)),"","Count"),"Capsules"),"Tablets")

+IF(ISERROR(VALUE(RIGHT(LEFT(A4,SEARCH(B4,$A4)-1),4))),0,VALUE(RIGHT(LEFT(A4,SEARCH(B4,$A4)-1),4)))
```

The formula has a limitation regarding the numbers is getting, and it's limited to 9999, more than that the formula trunks the result. Also for number 1 to 9 the formula may return error #value. This can be addressed changing the second formula if needed.

Comment: Curious about the purpose of the leading `+` there. The formula yields a `Variant/String`...

Comment: I use to put the + instead of = because it's faster (in a spanish keyboard) and excel doesn't make difference to start a formula. It's an habit I got of typing in a spanish keyboard where you need to use Shift for the =.

Comment: Interesting; I'd need to hit Shift to make a `+` ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

- Start with an IF statement `IF(-test-, -true-, -false-)`
- Populate the -test- portion. Say I first wanted to find 'Tablet'. I could use `...FIND("Tablet",A2)...` However, the issue here is if "Tablet" is not found it will throw an error so I would error-proof it like this `...IFERROR(Find("Tablet",A2), FALSE)...` which will return FALSE if "Tablet" is not found in cell A2.
- But I also want to look for 'Count' so I could use an OR along with that I already built up `...OR( IFERROR(Find("Tablet",A2), FALSE),  IFERROR(Find("Count",A2), FALSE) )` so this will OR together the outcomes - if either "Tablet" or "Count" is found, this function returns a number (and since it's a number, it's read as TRUE!)
- Now I throw that OR() equation into my IF for the -true-, then of course my  I could make as "Tablet" or "Count" or put a new equation there to specifically say what it found. And my -false- I can make `""`

At this point, I would have a complete equation which will check for "Count" or "Tablet" and spit out whatever is in my -true- equation. Otherwise, the cell would remain blank:
`IF(OR( IFERROR(Find("Tablet",A2), FALSE),  IFERROR(Find("Count",A2), FALSE) ), "Count/Tablet", "")`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a lightly-tested UDF using RegExp:

```
Function Amounts(txt)
    Dim re As Object, allMatches, m, rv, sep

    Set re = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    re.Pattern = "(\d+\s?(tablets|tablet|count|liquid))"
    re.ignorecase = True
    re.MultiLine = True
    re.Global = True

    Set allMatches = re.Execute(txt)
    For Each m In allMatches
        rv = rv & sep & m
        sep = ","
    Next m
    Amounts = IIf(rv <> "", rv, "(none)")
End Function
```

Usage:

```
=Amounts(A2)
```

[image]